# Class library types for a web/mobile project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

I want to develop a .NET core WebApi and consuming its services with web (angular) and mobile(xamarin).

I will use class library, but I'am not understanding what type of class library should I use.

When i tried to use portable class library targeting .Net Framework 4.5, ASP.NET 1.0 and XAMARIN. but then I can't install Entity Framework on this project.

The simple class library will not work with xamarin.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xZlB.png)

Comment: Xamarin shouldn't be involved with anything server-side.  You should only use it in your client.

Comment: EntityFramework 6 doesn't belong in a class library consumed by Xamarin. If you want to share models or other logic between server and client side, split that out from your data layer into a different class library.